# using a method to print an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, int

From my current code how would i print the array{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,88,99,100} using a method display and calling it using System.out.println(myobject.display()) in my main.

```
public TestA(){
    index = -1;
    iA = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,88,99,100};
}

public static String display(){
    String str = "";    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        str= str+ " ";
    }//for
    return str;
}//display
```

My current method display does not display anything.

Comment: Alternatively (for your future) you can call `Arrays.toString(iA)`

Comment: why should it display anything?

Answer (score 4):

```
public TestA()
{
    index = -1;
    iA = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,88,99,100};
    System.out.println(display(iA));
}

public static String display(int[] myData)
{
    String str = "";    
    for(int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++){
        str += myData[i]+ " ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Your statement in bold is false. -1

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux:please check it now.

Comment: What if myData[i%10]  ??

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar: Sorry Sir, I Didnt get you?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar: Got it Sir, instead of i as index i%10 can be given here as all values are divisble by 10 .yes its true :) , this is what you mean right?

Comment: @Sudhakar, sorry, i made a mistake. the suggestion was i%100, to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method and print the result. Also use the array `iA` in your method.

```
System.out.println(display());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is just adding an empty string to an empty string 10 times.  You are never adding in the text from your array based on the index `i`.  During your loop, you should be adding the space as well as the value at the current array position.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `display()` is indeed doing something. It is returning 10 spaces, which are being printed out in your main method. You need to actually use the array at some point. Try something like:

```
public TestA(){
    index = -1;
    iA = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,88,99,100};
}

public static String display(int[] iA){
    String str = "";    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        str= str + Integer.toString(iA[i]) + " ";
    }//for
    return str;
}//display
```

Comment: Sorry but is wrong. If is a static method, how is the iA[] array accesed?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar iA can be static.

Comment: It could be static, but it is passed in as a parameter anyway?

Comment: @Velox I think TestA is a class with a static attribute iA (even if this is a bad design), so no need to pass it as parameter in display

Comment: @ZouZou,initizalization of Static Variables in a non static method?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar It compiles and run, even if it's a bad pratice. http://ideone.com/yuEFBf